# Using the vim to align a series of python assignment statements, some of which include logic statements

Tags: vim

I would like to be able to align assignment statements using the "=" such as the following using vim:

```
var1 = a1[a1 >= 20]
variable2 = array2[array2 >= 20]
var_5 = arr3[arr3 != 10]
```

The problem is that vim's Align command will use the "=" that is used for the assignment statement and the one that is in the equal statement.  Then I get:

```
var1      = a1[a1 >         = 20]
variable2 = array2[array2 > = 20]
var_5     = arr3[arr3 !     = 10]
```

This is problematic both because, instead of increasing the readability, it ruins it, and because it ruins the logic operators.

I tried using the command

```
:AlignCtrl \<=\>
```

but that didn't help.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to alignment in vim, I use the [Tabular Plugin](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular). See Drew Neal's amazing screencast on tabular: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/

Essentially, tabular will align on text that matches a regular expression, e.g.

```
:Tabular /[<>=!]\+
```

input

```
var1 = a1[a1 >= 20]
variable2 = array2[array2 >= 20]
var_5 = arr3[arr3 != 10]
```

output

```
var1      = a1[a1         >= 20]
variable2 = array2[array2 >= 20]
var_5     = arr3[arr3     != 10]
```

Square brackets in a regular expression denote a character class, i.e. a set of single characters that will match. The regular expression `[<>=!]\+` means "match one or more occurrences of the characters `<`, `>`, `=`, or `!`". Because the `]` character marks the end of the character class, you must place directly after the opening `[` so that its meaning is unambiguous:

```
:Tabular /[][<>=!]\+
```

will allign the braces as well:

```
var1      = a1     [ a1     >= 20 ]
variable2 = array2 [ array2 >= 20 ]
var_5     = arr3   [ arr3   != 10 ]
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was not aware of Tabular, and the video was good.  I am also still a novice when it comes to regular expressions.  As I understand it, the expression you supplied will select any character within the brackets.  What about the expression tells it to align on a single = in the first instance, but on the various combinations in the second.  Also, what if I wanted to further align the square brackets as well?  Would I do a \] within the brackets?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure which aligning script you are using, and you didn't specify, but it probably supports regex and your idea was close. However your word boundary regex is not the correct option because `>` does count as a word boundary (it actually depends on your `'iskeyword'` option). You could try aligning in equal signs preceded by whitespace:

```
:AlignCtrl \s=
```

Or, if the space in this case is getting included in the align field and you want to remove it, use:

```
:AlignCtrl \s\zs=
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using the script by Dr. Chip.  I tried your suggestion above and it didn't help as posted, but when I simply did :Align \s= it works.  Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the plugin [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align). It let's you specify only first occurrence of a delimiter to be used for alignment.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of vim-easy-align.  Honestly, I hadn't thought of just doing the first one, which is often useful -so thanks!  Actually, I think that option is also available with Align.  However, there are often times when I want to align about multiple delimeters and I have other things mixed in.  I looked at the documentation that you pointed me to.  It looks like *= will automatically align about all operators that have ='s in them.  Is that correct?  Also, it looks like it will ignore included lines that do not have the operator in them at all, is that correct?